# Rails chain ActiveRecord joins

Tags: activerecord, join, associations

I'm making use of an Array of association names, and I'd like to perform joins to build an ActiveRecord::Relation object. I would like to do something like the following:

```
association_names = %w(assoc1 assoc2 assoc3 ... assocN)
my_relation = MyModel.where(nil)
association_names.each{|name| my_relation = my_relation.joins(name.to_sym) }
```

But this leads to the error message:

> ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'assoc2' was not
>   found; perhaps you misspelled it?

The complication is that the associations are not all joined directly to `MyModel`; instead `MyModel` is associated with `:assoc1`, and `Assoc1` is associated with `:assoc2`, and `Assoc2` is assoicated with `:assoc3`, etc.

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (my) join is complex, so it should not just be an Array. It should be more like:

```
my_relation.joins([{assoc1 => [assoc2, {assoc3 => assoc4}]}, assoc5])
```

If you're operating off of an Array of association names, there's not really a convenient way to achieve his, but you can write some extra code to test whether a given association belongs to the current model or not.

The following illustrates the concepts involved in such  a task, but beware that it is a bad example because it's neither thorough nor robust.

```
models = [MyModel]
joins = []
while associations.present? do
  associations.each do |a|
    models.each do |m|
      assoc_model = m.reflect_on_association(a)
      # assoc_model will be non-nil if there is an association for the given model and given name
      if assoc_model
        # add the associated class to models (for continued iteration)
        models << assoc_model.class_name
        # Somehow workout where in your complex Array of +joins+ this assoc this association belongs.
        # There are too many possible implementations to pick one for my time. 
        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```